# XPS with Windows Forms

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, xps, xpsdocument

What is the best way to **display** and **print** XPS files in a Windows Forms application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use WPF, you can host a WPF control inside a WinForms application - you don't have to rewrite your GUI in WPF or anything like that.

more information here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745781.aspx

Answer (score 3):

On my machine, XPS files open automatically thru IE.  I would just drop a WebBrowser control on the form and navigate to the XPS file then call the Print() method.

Answer (score 0):

I just call Process.Start(XpsRchVw.exe, "pathtofile")
if you have xps viewer EP installed then this will open your xps in xpsviewer and allow you to use it to print edit etc 
binks